# How can I repeat a specific iteration in a foreach loop in PHP?

Tags: php, foreach, iteration

As there is no iterator in PHP, the only way to loop through an array without getting the length of the array is to use foreach loop.

Let say I have the following loop:

```
foreach ($testing_array as $testing_entry) {
    $result = my_testing_api_call($testing_entry);
    if ($result == 'server dead')
        break;
    else if ($result == 'done') {
        // do something to handle success code
        continue;
    }
    else {
        sleep(5);
        // I want to retry my_testing_api_call with current $testing entry, but don't know what to write
    }
}
```

One way to do that is to use for loop instead.

```
for ( $i=0; $i < count($testing_array); $i++ ) {
    $result = my_testing_api_call($testing_entry[$i]);
    if ($result == 'server dead')
        break;
    else if ($result == 'done') {
        // do something to handle success code
        continue;
    }
    else {
        sleep(5);
        $i--; //so it will repeat the current iteration.
    }
}
```

The problem is that the `$testing_array` is not originally using number as index, so I have to do some data massage to use a for loop. Is there a way I can repeat a specific iteration in a foreach loop?

Comment: you could write a recursive function inside the loop?

Comment: Note that there *is* an iterator in the standard library of PHP: http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Perhaps a do-while will work for you.

Untested Code:

```
foreach ($testing_array as $testing_entry) {
    do {
        $result = my_testing_api_call($testing_entry);
        if ($result == 'server dead') {
            break 2;  // break both loops
        } elseif ($result == 'done') {
            // do something to handle success code
        } else {
            sleep(5);
            // I want to retry my_testing_api_call with current $testing entry, but don't know what to write
        }
    } while ($result !== 'done');
}
```

---

Or a single loop structure that destroys the input array as it iterates.

Untested Code:

```
$result = '';
while ($testing_array && $result !== 'server dead') {
    $result = my_testing_api_call(current($testing_array));
    if ($result == 'done') {
        // do something to handle success code
        array_shift($testing_array);
    } elseif ($result !== 'server dead') {
        sleep(5); // I want to retry my_testing_api_call with current $testing entry, but don't know what to write
    }
}
```

---

Or you can use your `for` loop by indexing `$test_array` with `array_values()` if you don't need the keys in your `// do something`.

```
$testing_array = array_values($testing_array);
for ($i=0, $count=count($testing_array); $i < $count; ++$i) {
    $result = my_testing_api_call($testing_entry[$i]);
    if ($result == 'server dead') {
        break;
    } else if ($result == 'done') {
        // do something to handle success code
    } else {
        sleep(5);
        --$i; //so it will repeat the current iteration.
    }
}
```

If you do need the keys down script, but you want to use `for`, you *could* store an indexed array of keys which would allow you to use `$i` to access the keys and maintain data synchronicity.

---

## My final suggestion:

Use `while (key($testing_array) !== null) {...}` to move the pointer without destroying elements.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/Kr2J4))

```
$array1 = [
    "one" => 1,
    "two" => 2,
    "three" => 3,
    "four" => 4
];

while (key($array1)!==null) {  // check if the internal pointer points beyond the end of the elements list or the array is empty
    $current = current($array1);
    $key = key($array1);
    echo "$key => $current\n";         // display current key value pair
    if ($current < 3) {                // an arbitrary condition
        echo "\t";
        $array1[$key] = ++$current;    // increment the current value
    } else {                           // current value is satisfactory
        echo "\t(advance pointer)\n";
        next($array1);                 // move pointer
    }
}
```

Output:

```
one => 1
    one => 2
    one => 3
    (advance pointer)
two => 2
    two => 3
    (advance pointer)
three => 3
    (advance pointer)
four => 4
    (advance pointer)
```

Comment: I wonder if this will work. The break will now only break the do-while loop, instead of breaking the foreach loop?

Comment: Correct.  It is a single break.

Comment: But in the original code, the break is supposed to break the foreach loop.

Comment: Ok.  It can be a double break. `break 2`

Comment: Um... can be a solution, but a do-while loop inside a foreach loop is really not that good in readability when the code in the middle is long. I would up vote but prefer not to mark as correct at this moment, hoping for a better answer.

Comment: I am happy to make adjustments if you can clarify your disinterest in the do-while.  It seems fitting, given your posted details.  What do you mean by _code in the middle is wrong _?

Comment: Updated to provide a single loop structure that iteratively removes the first element.  Sorry, answering from my phone takes longer.

Comment: @cytsunny  How am I doing with your question?  If your inner-script is lengthy, are you able to replace it with a custom function call in the loop structure?  That should keep it brief.  No?

Comment: Um.... still not something that I want. I was thinking if there are other ways to iterate through the array that don't need to move the logic to the outside loop. Like you don't need to put the logic outside when you use `break` / `continue`. But maybe that is the limit of a shit language like PHP. So I better mark as correct after a few days of waiting.

Comment: By the way, the solution in your last edit was what makes me ask this question. using a heavy function like array_values just to improve readability sounds stupid, but seems like that is the only way to do that in PHP.

Comment: @cytsunny I've added one final suggestion that demonstrates how to conditionally move the pointer and employs just one loop structure.  I think this is the best I can offer.  I trust that you can build your `break` and `sleep` functionality into this design.

Answer (score 2):

To repeat a single specific iteration you need to add a control mechanism, it is not an intended behavior after all.
There are many suggestions here, all of them are kinda over-engineered.

PHP is a high level derivate of C and both languages have the 'goto' operator, it has a bad reputation because people have historically used it too much.
In the end a foreach/while loop is internally nothing else than a 'goto' operation.

Here is the code:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value)
{
restart:
if ($value === 12345) goto restart;
}
```

That's how this should be done just keep in mind that this can cause an endless loop, like in the example.

Look at the next complicated version without goto:

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) while(1)
{
if ($value === 12345) continue;
break;
}
```

This is essentially the same as the goto, just with more code.
If you'd want to "break" or "continue" the foreach loop you'd write "break 2"  or "continue 2"

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to handle two different things in your loop, that makes it hard to write clean control flow. You could separate the retry-logic from the result handling:

```
function call_api_with_retry($entry) {
  do {
    if (is_defined($result)) sleep(5);
    $result = my_testing_api_call($entry);
  } while ($result != 'done' && $result != 'server dead');
  return $result;
}

foreach ($testing_array as $testing_entry) {
    $result = call_api_with_retry($testing_entry);
    if ($result == 'server dead')
        break;
    else if ($result == 'done') {
        // do something to handle success code
        continue;
    }
}
```

(there might be syntax errors, it's been a while since I wrote PHP code)